# howt to multipy content of dataset and matrix?

Tags: matlab

i want to multiply content of dataset from column 4 to column 10 with content of a matrix from column one to column 7.i write the code as below.but i get this error:Undefined function 'mtimes' for input arguments of type 'dataset'.
Measure = population(:,1:7)* CentralityMeasure;
 here is my code:

```
`clc;
close all;
clear all;
dataset1 = dataset('File','finalexcel.csv','Delimiter',',');
n = 7; 
pz = 100; 
a = rand(100,7);
zero = zeros(pz,1);
a = bsxfun(@rdivide,a.',sum(a.')).';
CentralityMeasure = dataset1(:,4:10);
population = zeros(pz,n);
population = rand(100,7);
population = bsxfun(@rdivide,population.',sum(population.')).';%create random number with sum equal 1 in each row
population = [population zero];
Measure = population(:,1:7)* CentralityMeasure;`
```

how can i fix it?thank for taking your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are trying to multiple a *dataset* which is char by double type. 
Solution:

```
CentralityMeasure  = double(dataset1(:,4:10));
```

Furthermore, use dot product:

```
Measure = population(:,1:7) .* CentralityMeasure;
```

Comment: affter your suggested code this error is showon: Matrix dimensions must agree

Comment: check this: `size(Measure,1) == size(CentralityMeasure,1)` . Are you sure that both dimensions are the same? Of course your columns have the same size, but how about rows?
By the way, why are you parsing your .CSV file as dataset?